# Need to create a pivot table but many years across with monthly data

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Sorry if this has been asked before.
I have a month wise product wise sales report spanning across 5 years.
Its only the quantity that is used in this data set. Its in excel and
rows are starting with the product names and columns are starting with
the months for example jan 2015 feb 2015 etc with respective product's qty
entered in respective month.

Is there a way to have a pivot showing only yearly totals for each product ?

I tried but hit a wall as in i cant figure out what will go where..

Thanks in advance
Greg

Comment: What is the format of the Column Headers? Is it formatted as Date, or as Text?

Comment: You could probably also do this Power Query. A data sample would be useful to help you figure out a solution.

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

Probably quite a few ways to accomplish this. If your data are consistent and you don't need much flexibility, then you could use SUMIFS formulas. Here, row 3 is a text version of the date.

```
Cell B3 formula: =TEXT(B2,"yyyy")
```

Then you could create SUMIFS formula like such:

```
Cell B9 formula: =SUMIFS($B4:$Y4,$B$3:$Y$3,B$8)
```

But if you really wanted a Pivot table, then a fairly simple solution is to add several more columns to your data. Just add a SUM column for each year, such as columns Z and AA below. Just create formulas in those cells to sum the year.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Am trying to show an image of the data that i am working with.

[The image is showing the data i am working with. Monthly quantity sold and row names are mentioned as product names.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJICD.png)

I am new to this so dont know if my image is showing.